# Oracle pivot table with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have 3 tables as below.

**TABLE 1:** COMPANY (contains company_id and company_name)

[image]

**TABLE 2:** CONFIGURATION (contains configuration_id and configuration_name)

[image]

**TABLE 3:** COMPANY_CONFIGURATION (Contains the configuration mapping for each company)
[image]

I am trying to display the configurations of each company in a pivot (dynamic columns) as below.

[image]

Below is the script which I have written

```
DECLARE
    columns_query VARCHAR2(32767);
    query VARCHAR2(32767);
    columns_list VARCHAR2(32767);
    result_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    -- Generate the column list dynamically
    SELECT LISTAGG('''' || company_name || '''', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY company_name)
    INTO columns_list
    FROM company;

    -- Build the dynamic SQL query
    columns_query := '
        SELECT
            configuration_id,
            configuration_name,
            ' || columns_list || '
        FROM (
            SELECT
                c.company_id,
                c.company_name,
                cn.configuration_id,
                cn.configuration_name,
                cc.config_value
            FROM
                company_configuration cc
            JOIN
                company c ON cc.company_id = c.company_id
            JOIN
                Configuration cn ON cc.configuration_id = cn.configuration_id
        ) src
        PIVOT (
            MAX(config_value)
            FOR company_name IN (' || columns_list || ')
        ) pivoted';

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL query
    OPEN result_cursor FOR columns_query;
    dbms_sql.return_result(result_cursor);

END;
/
```

However, in the script output, the company name is printed in all rows instead of the respective config_value. Please find the result below.

[image]

Questions

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. How can I display the respective config_value under each company column?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: from site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) ... fyi: I cannot see any of the images, so the question is incomprehensible